# How can I put my two-col layout's right column at the top when in iPad view?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have the following code, with a `flex-parent` class acting as a container and `flex-col` class for the columns:

```css
.flex-parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-parent .flex-col {
    flex: 1;
    margin-left: 5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid page page-dashboard flex-parent">
    <div class="flex-col widget-row">
        <div class="selector-wrapper">
            <div ng-repeat="(key, widget) in $ctrl.widgets" class="widget-selectors aligner">
                <span class="widget-name-selectors" ng-class="{'selected-dashboard-item': !widget.hidden, 'not-selected-dashboard-item': widget.hidden}" ng-click="$ctrl.toggleVisibility(widget)">
                        {{widget.name}}
                    </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div ng-repeat="bag in $ctrl.bags" dragula="'bag-one'" class="col-sm-12 bag flex-container" dragula-scope="$parent" id="widget-{{$index}}" dragula-model="bag">
            <div class="bag-item col-sm-6 flex-item" ng-repeat="item in bag" ng-style="item.style" id="item-{{item.id}}" ng-hide="item.hidden">
                <div class="panel-heading">{{item.name}}</div>
                <widget widget="item"></widget>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-col">
        <w-priority-tasks ng-if="::($ctrl.priorityTasks && $ctrl.priorityTasks.length)" task-list="::$ctrl.priorityTasks"></w-priority-tasks>
    </div>
</div>
```

right now the two columns are the way I want them, with the div at the bottom appearing on the far right. however, when the view shrinks from desktop to iPad, I would like the column on the far right to appear on the top. How can I accomplish this with flexbox?

Comment: can you add the working code on jsfiddle or codepen? Im sure all you need is `order`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `flex-direction: row-reverse;` to reverse the order of the flex items